# apt-get install nfs-common does not create an idmapd

Tags: 14.04, apt, nfs, client

I am trying to get NFSv4 client to work with `idmapd` and I try

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Unfortunately, this installs the expected files `/etc/default/nfs-common`, `/etc/idmapd.conf` etc., but exits with the following messages:

```
Setting up rpcbind (0.2.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
initctl: Unknown job: rpcbind
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1) ...
initctl: Unknown job: statd
initctl: Unknown job: gssd
initctl: Unknown job: idmapd
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sonny.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and this work for me :

`$ unset UPSTART_SESSION`

[here explain the problem.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120050/sudo-service-vsftpd-returns-unknown-job-vsftpd)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.